# how to make the graph of $1/x$ pass through $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$?

Tags: functions

I am trying to get a graph like this to pass through the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$:

[image]

How do I transform this, and more generally, equations of the form $\dfrac{1}{cx}$ (where $c$ is constant) so that they always pass through those $2$ points?

Comment: What transformations are you looking for? A translation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you have in mind an equation of the form $(y-k) = \frac{1}{x-h}$, but you started off by writing $1/x$ rather than an equation (that would give you a graph).  Why do you need the graph to pass through those two points?  Will it be used for something?  Or is it just an assigned exercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could translate the curve down and to the left (or up and to the right, focusing on the $x<0$ part). The new function takes the form:
$$y=\frac{1}{c(x+a)}-b$$
Plugging in points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ requires:
$$1=\frac{1}{ca}-b$$
$$0=\frac{1}{c(1+a)}-b$$
Which solves to:
$$a=b=\frac{1}{2}\left(\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{c}}-1\right)$$
In particular, the case $c=1$ gives a translated curve with parameter $a=b=\frac{\pm\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

You can play with this in this interactive [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5i18y72aye).

Comment: thanks, that graph is really helpful!